# Data Warehouse Design of Fact Tables

Tags: data-warehouse

I'm pretty new to data warehouse design and am struggling with how to design the fact table given very similar, but somewhat different metrics. Lets say you were evaluating the below metrics, how would you break up the fact tables (in this case company is a subset of client). Would you be able to use one table for all of this or would each metric being measured warrant its own fact table or would each part of the metric being measured be its own column in one fact table?

- Total company daily/monthly/yearly # of files processed
- Total company daily/monthly/yearly file sizes processed
- Total company daily/monthly/yearly # files errored
- Total company daily/monthly/yearly # files failed
- Total client daily/monthly/yearly # of files processed
- Total client daily/monthly/yearly file sizes processed
- Total client daily/monthly/yearly # files errored
- Total client daily/monthly/yearly # files failed

Comment: I think you should re-word your question and add some specifics.  What database are you using?  What does your input data look like?  For me those are usually the raw facts which create fact tables.  From there you can do all sorts of fun stuff.  But we need to know more.

Comment: This will eventually be in Redshift. Data input will come in the form of JSON supplied from a service. I'm working on the conceptual data model at this point. I assume that all of these similar metrics would be part of one fact table in its own column.

Comment: Also, what if the totals needed to be for a combination of day, week and month. How would this fact table be designed to combine the totals?

Comment: No. Data warehousing is all about understanding the business process. Don't get caught up in technology when designing facts. From your description this can be satisfied with one fact table, then any number of reporting/bi tools take care of the correct rollups, for the easiest most accessible example: an Excel pivot table. You should really have a play with an Excel pivot table then you will understand how these things can be automatically rolled up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By the looks of the measure names, I think you'll be served with a single fact table with a record for each file and a link back to a date_dim

```
create table date_dim (
    date_sk        int,
    calendar_date  date,
    month_ordinal  int,
    month_name     nvarchar,
    Year           int,
..etc you've got your own one of these ..
)
create table fact_file_measures (
    date_sk,
    file_sk,           --ref the file_dim with additonal file info
    company_sk,        --ref the company_dim with the client details
    processed  int,    --should always be one, optional depending on how your reporting team like to work
    size_Kb    decimal -- specifiy a size measurement, ambiguity is bad
    error_count int    -- 1 if file had error, 0 if fine
    failed_count int   -- 1 or file failed, 0 if fine
)
```

so now you should be able to construct queries to get everything you asked for

for example, for your monthly stats:

```
select 
    c.company_name,
    c.client_name,
    sum(f.file_count) total_files,
    sum(f.size_Kb)    total_files_size_Kb,
    sum(f.file_count) total_files,
    sum(f.file_count) total_files
from
    fact_file_measure f
    inner join dim_company c on f.company_sk = c.company_sk
    inner join dim_date d on f.date_sk = d.date_sk
where
    d.month = 'January' and d.year = "1984"
```

If you needed to have the side by side 'day/month/year' stuff, you can construct year and month fact tables to do the roll ups and join back via dim_date's month/year fields. (You could include month and year fields in the daily fact table, but these values may end up being miss-used by less experienced report builders) It all goes back to what your users actually want - design your fact tables to their requirements and don't be afraid to have separate fact tables - data warehouse is not about normalization, its about presenting the data in a way that it can be used.

Good luck

Comment: Thanks; that helped put all of this into perspective.